# Using verify on Spy object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I defined a spy bean:

```
@Bean
public IMyService myServiceSpy()
{
    return Mockito.spy(new MyServiceImpl());
}
```

In my test I want to capture the argument the service gets.
Of course if I'll define the service as mock instead of spy, it'll work, but I want to activate service's real method and continue the flow, because I need the return value to be calculated by it.

```
    @Inject
    private IMyService myServiceSpy;

    @Test
    public void myTest()
    {

    //act   
    //here invoking some service that will eventually invoke MyServiceImpl.

    //assert
    ArgumentCaptor<SomeObj> someObjCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SomeObj.class);

    try
    {               
       Mockito.verify(myServiceSpy, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).create(someObjCaptor.capture());                 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Assert.fail();
    }   
   assertEquals("some value" , someObjCaptor.getValue());
```

The strange thing is that the spy's method is activated again when verify() is called, but this time the method called with NULL parameters.

After that it's failing on assertion

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  No argument value was captured! You might have forgotten to use argument.capture() in verify()... ...or you used capture() in stubbing but stubbed method was not called. Be aware that it is recommended to use capture() only with verify()

Examples of correct argument capturing:
    ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
    verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
    assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```

I'm using the below to run the tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure you should be using `@Inject` to spy over your service.

This has worked fine for me in the past:

```
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.Spy;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.atLeastOnce;

...

@Spy
private MyServiceImpl myServiceSpy;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<SomeObj> someObjCaptor;

@Test
public void myTest()
{

    ...

    try
    {               
       verify(myServiceSpy, atLeastOnce()).create(someObjCaptor.capture());

       SomeObj someObj = someObjCaptor.get();

       // Assert anything
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Assert.fail();
    }   

    ...

}

@Bean
public MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl()
{
    return new MyServiceImpl();
}
```

The annotations really simplify the code. Once you get used to them, it becomes much simpler to read the code, and to type it in =)

Comment: If I'm using @Spy, then I'm getting NULL as myServiceSpy.

Comment: Sorry, I think that is because the Bean is not present on the Test context. I've updated the code.

Comment: Still NULL. But why does it matter? the both ways should be fine for defining spy object.

Comment: I saw in some place that it should be defined like "@Inject @Spy IMyService myServiceSpy" . this way I'm not getting NULL, but getting exception on verify - Argument passed to verify() is of type ....  and is not a mock!

Comment: Dumb question, but is your test class annotated with Mockito? Like `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`?

Comment: But in our case it's @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that the `Spy` and `Captor` methods are intended to use without the `MockitoJUnitRunner`. =\

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of Spring AOP as I found in this article:

https://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/

I solved it by creating new class that will invoked the original bean.
The new class will be spied in @Configuration class.

```
public class MyServiceImplSpy implements IMyServiceImpl
{

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("myServiceImpl")  
    private IMyService myService;  //the original bean          

    public String create(SomeObj someObj)
    {
        return myService.create(someObj);
    }

}
```